# Does an information-theoretical approach proof the equivalence of total order and total chaos?

Tags: entropy, information

In the light of information-theory, are a state with maximum and minimum entropy the same?

In the case of gas (maximum entropy), one needs very little words to describe a **part** of the system, which looks the same as the **whole** system. The same holds for a crystal at zero temperature.

In both cases, one needs very little words to describe both systems (contrary to systems, like living organisms that lay between a minimum and maximum entropy)

Comment: [Obligatory 8-bit Theater](https://www.nuklearpower.com/2010/03/09/episode-1223-make-the-truth/).

Comment: **"_are a state with maximum and minimum entropy the same?_":** Do you mean this literally, like if the two states are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, because you need little words to describe the overall structure of both, while for describing us humans (who find themselves between these two extremes) you need zillions huge books to describe our structure.

Comment: I don't understand the article you refer to at all.

Comment: "Minimum" and "maximum" have the same number of letters. Does that make them the same?

Comment: @D.Halsey-Yes. you can describe them with the same number of words. Their **meaning** though is **not ** the same.

Comment: @Nat-It's stil not clear to me but funny it certainly is!! :- )